# PostgreSQL's table oid is not found in database

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about PostgreSQL's table oid.
I create a table. oid is 24622

(-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   8192 Nov 29 **17:45 24622**)

and I found also modified files at the same time.

(-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  73728 Nov 29 **17:45 12741**)

(-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  32768 Nov 29 **17:45 12744**)

(-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  65536 Nov 29 **17:45 12764**)

(-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  57344 Nov 29 **17:45 12767**)

but those tables are not found in same database, no one is found.

```
ksh2=# select oid,relname from pg_class where oid = '12741';

 oid | relname 

-----+---------

(0 rows)
```

How can I find those tables???
(I also change schema, and try to find, but no one is found)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A filename doesn't necessarily [correspond with `oid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html):

> Note that while a table's filenode often matches its OID, this is not
>   necessarily the case; some operations, like TRUNCATE, REINDEX, CLUSTER
>   and some forms of ALTER TABLE, can change the filenode while
>   preserving the OID.

The filename is stored in the `relfilenode` column:

> Name of the on-disk file of this relation; zero means this is a
>   "mapped" relation whose disk file name is determined by low-level
>   state

So try searching for the `relfilenode`:

```
select name, relkind from pg_class where relfilenode = 12741;
```

The `relkind` column tells you what type of object the file represents:

```
r = ordinary table
i = index
S = sequence
v = view
c = composite type
t = TOAST table
f = foreign table
```

Comment: Thank you Andomar, but not found that info. like below. ksh2=# select *  from pg_class where relfilenode = 12741;    (0 rows)

Comment: And 'select oid, *  from pg_class;' I print all information. And find that numbers (12741 , 12744, ...) but no one is found there. It's so strange.

Comment: Double check you're looking in the correct `base` directory for the right database and database instance?

Comment: Yes, right database, and right directory. but I can't find using this sql 'select oid, * from pg_class;'